# Filename reading problem when converting to exe with cx_Freeze module

Tags: python, filenames, cx-freeze, py2exe

I created a file called dork.py in Python and wrote the following inside the file:

```
import os,time
    
print(os.path.basename(__file__))
time.sleep(3)
```

as a result it prints dork.py on the screen
In the setup.py I created for cx_Freeze, I wrote the following:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
    
build_exe_options = {
    'packages': ['os','time'],
    'include_files':['/']
}
    
setup(
    name='YourAppName',
    version='1.0',
    description='Your App Description',
    options={'build_exe': build_exe_options},
    executables=[Executable('dork.py')]
)
```

When I run the exe file I want it to print dork.exe but it says dork.py. I tried this with pyinstaller and pyinstaller was giving an error

How can i solve this

I expected it to print dork.exe but it says dork.py

Answer (score 1):

the `__file__` will point to the original python file after freezing, this is the way cx_freeze or pyinstaller "patches" these variables when it freezes the modules.

a simple way to make it return `.exe` when the app is frozen is outlined in the [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files)

```py
import sys

if getattr(sys, "frozen", False):
    # The application is frozen
    script_path = sys.executable
else:
    # The application is not frozen
    script_path = __file__

print(script_path)
```